# Pushing a local file to Github

Tags: git, push

I've pushed a local edited file to my GitHub account, but when I check my GitHub account; the edited file that i pushed is not showing up.

I have used the Git command `git push origin master` and got the message `Everything up-to-date`.

Note my development environment is on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: you do not provide enough info to help; what is the output of "git remote -v"?

Comment: The output of 'git remote -v' is as follow: origin https://github.com/michatay/ProgrammingAssignment2.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/michatay/ProgrammingAssignment2.git (push)

Comment: Can someone answer my question abovel?

Comment: Have you done any research? For instance this is a [great resource about git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Answer (score 1):

If the file is already not in git you should add it with:

```
git add file
```

when you make changes to a file be sure to first commit them before pushing

```
git commit -a
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

To push to github via SSH you need to include git@ in front of the URL.  Some examples from the Pro Git book (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes):

```
$ git remote -v
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your remote origin is set to the GitHub repo URL.

Then make sure your git index is indexing the file you're trying to update (make sure it's being tracked by git index).

`git add filename`

then commit:

`git commit -m "Changed the file"`

`git push origin master`

If that doesn't work, your auth method or info is incorrect.